# c++ algorithm что то пошло не так

Tags: c++, алгоритм, ubuntu

написал вроде все правильно, но не работает

использовал библиотеку algorithm, vector

Вот код

```
#include <iostream> //output, input
#include <string> //string
#include <thread> //thread
#include <chrono> //for units
#include <ctime> //for time(0)
#include <deque> //deque STL
#include <functional> //function
#include <vector> //vector STL

#include <algorithm>

    // namespaces //
using namespace std;
using namespace this_thread;
using namespace chrono;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(string name, unsigned short int age, unsigned short int rating)
    {
        this->age = age;
        this->name = name;
        this->rating = rating;
    }

    string GET_name(){return name;}
    int GET_age(){return age;}
    int GET_rating(){return rating;}



    string name;
    unsigned short int age;
    unsigned short int rating;
};

    // PROGRAM //
void Program()
{
    vector<Student> Peoples 
    {
        Student("Danil",13,786),
        Student("Andrey",49,861),
        Student("Masha",21,569),
        Student("Pasha",4,4),
        Student("Danil",15,891)
    };

    sort(Peoples.begin(),Peoples.end(),[](Student& one, Student& two){return one.GET_rating() > two.GET_rating();});

    auto koko = remove(Peoples.begin(),Peoples.end(),[](Student& a){return a.age < 10;}); //Error в вот этой строке

    Peoples.erase(koko,Peoples.end());

    cout<<"Имя\t\tВозраст\t\tБал\t\t\tВсего: "<<Peoples.size()<<"\n"<<endl;
    for(auto el:Peoples)
    {
        cout<<el.GET_name()<<"\t\t"<<el.GET_age()<<"\t\t"<<el.GET_rating()<<endl;
    }
}

    // main //
int main()
{
    const auto _BEGIN_ = high_resolution_clock::now();
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");
    srand(time(0));
    cin.exceptions(ios::failbit | ios::badbit);

    Program();

    const auto _END_ = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const int TIME_FOR_PROGRAM = duration_cast<microseconds>(_END_-_BEGIN_).count();
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\033[1;32mProgram completed in "<<TIME_FOR_PROGRAM<<"mcs\033[0m"<<endl<<endl;
}
```

я нарушил инкапсуляцию чтобы перебрать все варианты)

Вот ошибка:

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

Comment: и да, некоторые библиотеки я просто так подключил

Comment: О каких "библиотеках" вы вообще ведете речь? Где описание того, что должен делать весь этот код?

Comment: Не `remove`, а `remove_if`. Не тот алгоритм вызываете...

Comment: functional deque

Comment: Harry, точно)))))

Comment: С каких это пор стандартные заголовки стали называться "библиотеками"?

Comment: эмм это по сути библиотека

Comment: Нет, это не библиотека. Библиотека тут всего одна - стандартная - и подключить или отключить ее вы не можете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, `remove` принимает значение, с которым выполняется сравнение. Для применения предиката нужно использовать `remove_if`.

Далее, я бы рекомендовал заменить

```
const int TIME_FOR_PROGRAM = duration_cast<microseconds>(_END_-_BEGIN_).count();
```

на

```
const auto TIME_FOR_PROGRAM = duration_cast<microseconds>(_END_-_BEGIN_).count();
```

Тогда останется просто проигнорировать предупреждение в строке

```
srand(time(0));
```

или все же использовать более продвинутые возможности `<random>`.

Comment: нет, мне нужно именно int.

srand(time(0)) вовсе не вызывает предупреждения

Comment: Возможно, уровень предупреждений занижен... Впрочем, я проверял на VC++.

Comment: так как я на линуксе я использую g++